# How to have Solr ngrams include spaces

Tags: solr

I am using solr to search names and want to match on partial matches. Using a minimum of 2 I get the following ngrams for "Bob Smith":

- bo
- bob
- sm
- smi
- smit
- smith

This however does not include "bob s" and returns nothing if I search that query. What options are there for including that format in ngrams? Here is the fieldtype I am using:

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using different tokenizers, the results will be different. The KeywordTokenizer will give you only the search input as a single token directly. Using the StandardTokenizer will work, but will give 'smith bob' as a suggestion to 'bob' smith' as well.

An alternative is to [index the content as shingles as well](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) - allowing you to create shingles from tokens (example given with just two used for shingle generation):

bob smith jr. => bob smith, smith jr.

.. and then generate edgengrams based on that, giving you:

bo
  bob
  bob 
  bob s
  bob sm
  ...

etc. The shingle factory will also include the actual token by default, so you should still be able to find just 'smith', etc.

```
<analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
</analyzer>
```

.. should give you more tokens that allow you match tokens following each other. You can adjust `maxShingleSize` if you want more than just two sequential tokens to be included.

Also, if you just want to do autocomplete from the beginning of the text, using a KeywordTokenizer with a Lowercasefilter for indexing and using a wildcard for searching will work (as long as you lowercase the text before sending it to Solr, as all analysis is skipped for wildcards). This would also work with edgengram together with a KeywordTokenizer.

Comment: This solution worked for me in terms of the ngram being created but for some reason if I search "bob s" i get nothing but if i search "bob sm" I get the desired result. I've tried with both with mm 1 and 2.

Comment: Use the Analysis tab under the administration interfaceto see where the comparison breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the KeywordTokenizerFactory on the index analyzer as well as the query analyzer, like this:

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

This way, when indexing you will apply the edgeNgram filter to the entire string, rather than the tokens. It will be tokenized as "bob smith" (instead of the "bob", "smith" you had in the StandardTokenizer) then filtered as "b", "bo", "bob", "bob s", etc.